# Unable to create Spring InternalResourceViewResolver due to conversionService?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm getting the following error creating a view resolver:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/webmvc-config.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'prefix'; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No class 'java.lang.String' was registered
```

My spring webmvc config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.web" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" />

    <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.data.repository.support.DomainClassConverter">
        <constructor-arg ref="conversionService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

</beans>
```

Does it has something to do with the conversionService?

Comment: What happens if you use normal `<property>` elements?

Comment: @Sotirios same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to register custom converters or formatters, you could try removing the conversionService bean declaration as well as the conversion-service attribute from the mvc:annotation-driven element.

Just having `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` is enough to enable default formatting rules:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-formatting-mvc

Comment: I need the conversionService to populate the Spring Data DomainClassConverter